# $u$~$N(0,A)$ and z$|u$~$N(u,1)$ how to show that $u|z$~$N(Bz,B)$ where $B=A/(A+1)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

$u$~$N(0,A)$ and $z|u$~$N(u,1)$ how to show that $u|z$~$N(Bz,B)$ where $B=A/(A+1)$ ?

[image: Empirical Bayes and Large Scale Interference]

Comment: Knowing $f_U$ and $f_{Z\mid U}$ yields $f_{U,Z}$, which yields $f_{U\mid Z}$. Which part of this program have you trouble with?

Comment: what is $f(U,Z)$ ? $f(U,Z)=?$

Comment: Never wrote $f(U,Z)$, but $f_{U,Z}$ the joint density of $(U,Z)$.

Comment: *Which part of this program have you trouble with?*

Comment: Somebody is erasing their footprints...

Comment: Hello, I am interested in solving the same problem, is there a good guide I can use to better understand the manipulation of the u ~ N(0,A) type objects? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$p(\mu|z) \propto p(z|\mu)p(\mu)$$

After you plug it $p(z|\mu)$ and $p(\mu)$ and you will find $p(\mu|z)$ has a pdf that is normal. And you can easily derive its mean and variance.

Comment: but what is $p(z)$ ? $N(0,1)$ ?

Comment: @Qbik There is no $p(z)$ involved here. You only need the conditional distribution of $p(z|\mu)$.